# GetTempFileName appears to be broken on Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, windows-10

I have an MFC program that uses `GetTempFileName`.  On Windows 7 it works correctly, however when I take the same code to Windows 10 it produces garbage.

```
TCHAR temp_dir[1024];
GetTempPath(1024,temp_dir);
TCHAR temp_file[1024];
GetTempFileName("C:\\","udb",0,temp_file);
std::cout << "Temp DB Path: " << temp_file << std::endl;
```

On Windows7:

```
Temp DB Path: C:\udb2145.tmp
```

On Windows10:

```
Temp DB Path: o▒
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code?  Or is there a different function I should be using?

Comment: I suspect on your Windows 10 machine you're doing a Unicode build. All those TCHAR arrays are turning into `wchar_t` which `std::cout` can't handle. Try `std::wcout` instead.

Comment: `GetTempFileName` takes three `TCHAR`-based strings, yet you give it only one. The other two, you just assume it wants `char`-based strings.

Comment: You neglected error checking and reaped your just dessert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first of all, when I tested your example, GetTempFileName returns 0, which means that it encountered an error (return value for success is non-zero temp file identifier). GetLastError returns -5, which means: "Access Denied", and I highly doubt that non-administrative applications can write to "C:\" (at least under Windows 8+).

The rubbish values you are seeing, that are being printed, are because you didn't initialize your temp_file array. You should do it like this:

```
TCHAR temp_file[1024] = {0};
```

And, to make your code work, store the temp file in the actual temp folder:

```
GetTempFileName(temp_dir,"udb",0,temp_file);
```

EDIT: And, as one of the commenters already pointed out, if your code uses unicode, you will need wcout to output the file name correctly. Otherwise you will see only the first character of the file path. But that will affect outputting to the console.

Comment: "*you will see only the first character of the file path*" - Actually, in a Unicode build, you won't see any characters at all.  `std::cout` does not have an `operator<<(wchar_t*)` defined, but it does have an `operator<<(void*)` instead, which will output the memory address of the array itself, not its content.

Comment: It's clearly not a Unicode build because of the use of `"udb"`. And there's no point in initializing `temp_file`. Proper error checking renders that needless. That's the key.